# Search for file with part of its name and add to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, os.walk

Hello all I have files saved in certain directory.

```
dir ="/user/raw/samples"
```

And I need get all the files ends with certain string into dictionary  `dic_x` and  other into dictionary `dic_z`.

Here are the files names in the `dir`:

```
SAP_XCV_1980_H7LYVDRXX_2_ALPH_C_cR_c1_v1_0_FCDSSA_DDDD_S14_L002_R1_001_MM_1.fz.gz
SAP_XCV_1980_H7LYVDRXX_2_ALPH_C_cR_c1_v1_0_FCDSSA_DDDD_S14_L002_R2_001_MM_1.fz.gz
SAP_XCV_1980_H7LYVDRXX_2_ALPH_C_cR_c1_v1_0_FCDSSA_DDDD_S14_L001_R2_001_MM_1.fz.gz
SAP_XCV_1980_H7LYVDRXX_2_ALPH_C_cR_c1_v1_0_FCDSSA_DDDD_S14_L001_R1_001_MM_1.fz.gz
```

And I have two dictionaries

```
 import sys
import os
import subprocess
import glob
import fnmatch
import re
    listF = ['ALPH']
    FH_sample = listF
    dic_x = {}
    dic_z = {}

    for line in FH_sample:
        dic_x[line.strip().split('\n')[0]] =[]
        dic_z[line.strip().split('\n')[0]] =[]

        for root, sub, file in os.walk(dir):
            for name in file:
                if name.endswith(".fz.gz"):
                    m1 = re.search('(.*)_R1', file)
                    m2 = re.search('(.*)_R2', file)
                if m1 and m1.group(1) in dic_x:
                    dic_x[m1.group(1)].append(file)
                if m2 and m2.group(1) in dic_z:
                    dic_z[m2.group(1)].append(file)
```

However, I am not able to get all the values inside the dictionary with the above lines of code. I need the dictionaries like following,

```
dic_x = {'ALPH': ['SAP_XCV_1980_H7LYVDRXX_2_ALPH_C_cR_c1_v1_0_FCDSSA_DDDD_S14_L001_R1_001_MM_1.fz.gz','SAP_XCV_1980_H7LYVDRXX_2_ALPH_C_cR_c1_v1_0_FCDSSA_DDDD_S14_L002_R1_001_MM_1.fz.gz']}

dic_z = {'ALPH': ['SAP_XCV_1980_H7LYVDRXX_2_ALPH_C_cR_c1_v1_0_FCDSSA_DDDD_S14_L001_R2_001_MM_1.fz.gz','SAP_XCV_1980_H7LYVDRXX_2_ALPH_C_cR_c1_v1_0_FCDSSA_DDDD_S14_L002_R2_001_MM_1.fz.gz']}
```

Currently `dic_x` and `dic_z` looks like this,

```
dic_z = {'ALPH': []}
dic_x = {'ALPH': []}
```

Comment: Why were you not able to get all the values in the dictionaries do you have other variants of those file names?

Comment: What's samples1, samples2 and what do you mean "not able to get all the values inside the dictionary"? What does dic_x and dic_z actually contain after you run your code?

Comment: @tobifascI have edited my question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of list

```
import os
import fnmatch
path = "test_images/"
x_list = ([f for f in os.listdir(path) if fnmatch.fnmatch(f, "*.png")])
z_list= ([f for f in os.listdir(path) if fnmatch.fnmatch(f, "*.bmp")])
dic_x = {'ALPH' : x_list }
dic_z = {'ALPH': z_list}
```

In your case you can replace `*.png` with `*R1_001_MM_1.fz.gz` and `*.bmp` with `*R2_001_MM_1.fz.gz'`. Also `test_images/` with `/user/raw/samples/`

Comment: Hello and thanks for your attempt, but I did not understand what do you mean by files, file2 here?

Comment: I tried the solution it does not create the dictionary automatically. Because I have more samples and this way does is more hardcoded